# Odd wrapping of pending flags

Tags: bug, status-completed, design

With this latest maintenance outage came a new UI around the helpful flags that one can see on the profile.

On MSE the pending flags looks like:

> [image]

On Photography (a particularly challenging site design), it looks like:

> [image]

On Programmers, it wraps funny:

> [image]

The screenshots above are from IE 10, though the issue of wrapping of the text is still visible in Safari and other webkit browsers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One case where reuse came to bite me...

Turns out that `.subheader` has a `:before` and `:after` directives (but only here on programmers), which screwed up with the table layout that this sidebar has.

I've made some changes to the markup and CSS so this is fixed (with you in the next build).

Comment: And verified fixed. Thank you.